# iterate through jSON with Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, mean

I am using Angular to iterate through citynames of a JSON file in MongoDB, but I can't seem to get it done. I only want the citynames

The JSON file in MongoDB is:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("592409faf1f5831ca882ad39"), 
"city" : "Aalsmeer", 
"phoneLG" : "0101-101 101"
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("592409faf1f5831ca882ad39"), 
"city" : "Amerongen", 
"phoneLG" : "0101-010 010"
}
```

This is my Angular:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl2', function($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams){
  $scope.currentCity = function(){
   $http.get("/getdata").then(function(response){
     angular.forEach(response.data) {
       console.log(response);
     }
   });
  };
});
```

And the HTML I'm using it in:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl2" ng-init="currentCity()">
   {{the citynames}}
</div>
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  you seem to be using `ng-init` (incorrectly, I might add) to call a function that gets data asynchronously, and then when the data gets returned, you loop through it and do a `console.log`.  nowhere in this code do you actually save the data for use in your HTML. (i.e. save the data to `$scope`).

Comment: Could You please paste entire response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl2', function($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams) {

    loadCities();

    function loadCities() {
        $http.get("/getdata").then(function(response){
            $scope.cities = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl2">
    <div ng-repeat="city in cities"> {{ city.city }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a little bit how I want it, but how can I use the result of {{city.city}} in my controller for further use. Because I need the citynames to be compared to a different value

Comment: I don't understand what you really want